# FFmpeg-python System can not find the file specified

Tags: python

i am a beginner in python , and have a very noobish question. While using ffmpeg-python with my very very basic script which should just combine an audio and video file, i am stuck with this error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Filnames and Folders do exist.

Do you have any idea why this happened ? Thank you so much

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben Catman\PycharmProjects\ffmpeg\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    ffmpeg.output(audio, video, "C:/Youtube/output.mp4").run(overwrite_output=True)
  File "C:\Users\Ben Catman\PycharmProjects\ffmpeg\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 313, in run
    process = run_async(
  File "C:\Users\Ben Catman\PycharmProjects\ffmpeg\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 284, in run_async
    return subprocess`your text`.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\Ben Catman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Ben Catman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Windows uses \\ not / for filenames.  Unless you use raw strings, you will need to escape the \ (\\ ) as it's also the standard escape character.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note that it's the ffmpeg executable, not your mp4 file, that the code is trying to find here. Where do you have that executable installed? How are you specifying its location to your code?

Comment: My bad, i asumed ffmpeg was already installed on this system - it was not ;) Does it make sense to install the exe into my root directory?